# Dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
# Initialize an empty dictionary: counts_dict
counts_dict = {}

# Iterate over the file chunk by chunk
for chunk in pd.read_csv('tweets.csv', chunksize=10):

    # Iterate over the column in DataFrame
    for entry in chunk['lang']:
        if entry in counts_dict.keys():
            counts_dict[entry] += 1
        else:
            counts_dict[entry] = 1

# Print the populated dictionary
print(counts_dict)
```

Can anyone explain even though dictionary `counts_dict = {}` is an empty dictionary, how the `if-else` condition is matched if the `counts_dict` is an empty dictionary in below part of the code :-

```
for entry in chunk['lang']:
    if entry in counts_dict.keys():
        counts_dict[entry] += 1
    else:
        counts_dict[entry] = 1
```

Comment: `counts_dict` is empty on the *first* iteration, but then  it fills up. BTW a `collections.Counter()` would be a natural way to do this

Comment: Here `else` condition will create keys and values on first iteration. Then in case of match in upcoming iterations, `if` logic is performed

Comment: As an aside, do not do: `if entry in counts_dict.keys()` just use `if entry in counts_dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time the `if` is executed, the dictionary will be empty, so `entry in count_dicts.keys()` will be `False`. As a result, it will execute the `else:` block, which assigns to `count_dict[entry]`. So the dictionary is no longer empty.

On the next iteration, if `entry` is the same key it just added, the `if` condition will be `True`, and it will increment that dictionary element. If it's a different key, it will create a new dictionary element for that.

This keeps repeating for each entry in `chunk['lang']` -- the first time an entry is encountered, it creates a new dictionary element for it, while repeated entries add 1 to the corresponding element. At the end, each dictionary element contains the count of its key.

You can see this happening if you put:

```
print(count_dict)
```

in the `for` loop, after the `if/else` block.

Comment: Thanks Barmer, i got it :)

Comment: Hey, you had suggested something to try can you please write it for me again.

Comment: You deleted your earlier comment, I thought you figured it out yourself. You can use `print(count_dict[entry])` to see the count of the current word. The reason I suggested `print(count_dict)` was so you can see how the whole thing is growing.

Comment: ok, so it is iterating on each key in lang column and counting the values in that particular key, then it goes to new key and again the if condition is false so else condition is True and the count_dict gets updated with value 1 ?

Comment: Sometimes the `if` condition is true, sometimes it's false. It depends on whether it's the first time the word appears in the list or it's a repetition.

Comment: The whole point of this is to count the number of repetitions of each word in `chunk['lang']`

Comment: {'und': 2, 'et': 1, 'en': 97} - thats the output. 'und' and 'et' and 'en' are the keys here. so what happens when the counting for the first key 'und' is completed. How does the code starts with the next key 'en'.

Comment: The first time it encounters `en` in the input, `en in count_dict.keys()` is false, so it goes to the `else:` block, which does `count_dict['en'] = 1`. That creates the new element in the dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by "counting for the first key is completed"? It's not doing each key in order. It just counts each word as they appear in the `lang` column of the dataframe.

Comment: Did you put `print(count_dict)` in the loop? You should see how it's growing after each word.

Comment: I did i can see it grow. its more clear now, maybe i am thinking in a wrong direction. How can print the tweets.csv file? I should see how the lang is populated in the file.

Comment: I am accessing it through DataCamp website, i dont have the file!, its a learning portal. they have preloaded the file. I dont have access.

Comment: I tried that , its simply printing below: 
<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x7f681c91b2e8>

Comment: OK, try `print(open('tweets.csv', 'r').read())` to see the full text of the file.

Comment: I guess i am bothering you, just tell me this last one.
Is 'lang' a key in the dictionary chunk, something like :- {"lang": "und", "lang": "en" ...............................................}

Comment: I could read the file. They code is counting the lang in the dataframe chunk. Thanks a ton. Really appreciate the help.